# Huawei ThemeStudio - font change

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I recently joined the Huawei developer community and would like to start developing Huawei themes for mobile phones. I downloaded the ThemeStudio app and everything makes sense to me, except for one thing.

Why is it not possible to change the font? It is only possible to replace the digits, but not the text itself. Does the font always have to be a default? Is it up to the user to change it, or is there some way to change the font when uploading? When I look at the themes on my Huawei Honor phone created by others, they all have the font changed.
I've gone through all the documentation and tutorials, but nowhere can I find an answer to my question. As a new user, I am quite confused, hence I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to changing the font of the lock screen in the theme package?

If you want to change all fonts provided by the mobile phone system, Theme Studio does not support the creation of fonts. This type of font is an independent resource type and is not open to designers except Chinese Mainland.

If you just want to change the font on the lock screen before the time, you can use the image writing method to achieve. For details, you could refer to [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/content/time-0000001074625954).

Comment: Specifically I meant this in the context of creating a large scope theme, hence generally changing the font of all text. I have a theme design that includes a specific font that fits that (MRF Lemonberry Sans). Then I go to the ThemeStudio where I redesign the theme, except for the font, which I would like to incorporate into the theme either from an external source or at least from some existing Huawei database. So, my question is: is there any way to incorporate other than the default font into the theme before selling it?

Comment: hi@nub, thank you for your feedback, and as the team confirms, we do not currently support this approach by now.

Comment: Do you expect to support this function/feature at some point? I don't think a design without a custom font can really be seen as something designers would be proud to publish.

Comment: yes@Matěj Zmítko, according to the ThemeStudio team's confirmation, this issue does not belong to Themes Studio, but the team is planning to support this in the future.